# Transactional sms HTTP into CF7 plugin

Tags: http, post, action

I need to integrate transcation sms http into Contact form 7 plugin. The sms gateway provider instructs that , kindly add POST action method into your php form it will work. I am newbie fix this issue, plz help me :(

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little confusing for me to fully comprehend but I am going to clarify what I understood from it.

Are you trying to enable ability to send SMS from your Wordpress site?

To do this, you can use the [WordPress SMS plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-sms/installation/)

Nexmo, where I work, provides an SMS API that is compatible with this plugin and can easily send SMS messages in over 200 countries.

The SMS API is extremely reliable, safe, & easy to integrate (simple HTTP call)

If this didn't answer your question & you were looking to send an SMS using an SMS API in PHP, you can find sample code below showing how to integrate this in PHP (fill in required parameters)

```
<?php
$url = 'https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?' . http_build_query([
    'api_key' => API_KEY,
    'api_secret' => API_SECRET,
    'to' => YOUR_NUMBER,
    'from' => NEXMO_NUMBER,
    'text' => 'Hello from Nexmo'
]);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Here is the documentation for [Nexmo's SMS API](https://docs.nexmo.com/index.php/sms-api)

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer :)

Comment: @vinodselvaraj no worries! I just read that WordPress SMS plugin is also works w/ CF7!